# iOS PDFKit Disable vertical scroll bounce

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview, pdfkit

How does one disable scroll bounce in a `PDFView` using **PDFKit**?

The view where the PDF is shown doesn't have a *scroll bounce* option.

Here's my code:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: pdfObject, ofType: "pdf") {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {

        pdfView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight,
                                    .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin]

        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displaysPageBreaks = true
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument

        pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 4.0
        pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit        
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance (for what is likely a ridiculously simple question!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an exported API to set the `PDFView` desired *bouncing* behavior.

Having said that, you can (safely) exploit a `PDFView` implementation detail to hack your way around it for now:

```
extension PDFView {

    /// Disables the PDFView default bouncing behavior.
    func disableBouncing() {
        for subview in subviews {
            if let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView {
                scrollView.bounces = false
                return
            }
        }
        print("PDFView.disableBouncing: FAILED!")
    }
}
```

and then use it like this in your code:

```
pdfView.disableBouncing()
```

**Caveat**. Please keep in mind that such solution *might* break in future iOS releases. Nevertheless, rest assured your app won't crash as a result (you only *won't* be disabling the bouncing behavior at all).

Comment: Hi Paulo, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this doesn't have any effect. However thanks for letting me know I'm not missing a 'bounce' behavior attribute. Might have to wait for an update on PDFKit form apple.

Comment: @NicholasFarmer Hmm... I did a quick test here and was able to successfully disable the bouncing behavior on the `PDFView`. Will upload a short gist when I get a chance...

Comment: Hey @NicholasFarmer, [run this code in a Swift Playground](https://gist.github.com/pmattos/f6adb5f2c03bb6c3a3ccfff340bd3d30)  in Xcode (be sure the *Live View* is showing) and you will see that the *vertical scroll bouncing* is indeed disabled. Comment out the `pdfView.disableBouncing()` line to enable it back.

Comment: Hi Paulo, apologies for the late reply. I went back and re-tested and still didn't work...however after recent update and upgrade to swift 5 - this now works beautifully. Many thanks for your input. Your answer has been accepted and upvoted. Kind regards

Comment: Hey @NicholasFarmer, glad to hear that ;) Good luck with your app!